# How to listen all events in appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get all callbacks from appdelegate with custom framework. But I couldn't figured out how can I do this ?

I'm trying to get all callbacks which is returned from appdelegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have all the callback, Following is the list of `UIApplication` notifications you can register for.

```
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationDidEnterBackground: NSNotification.Name

@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationWillEnterForeground: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationDidBecomeActive: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationWillResignActive: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationWillTerminate: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientation: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSNumber with new orientation

public static let UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSNumber with old orientation

// userInfo dictionary key for status bar orientation
public static let UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrame: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSValue with new frame

public static let UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrame: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSValue with old frame

// userInfo dictionary key for status bar frame
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationBackgroundRefreshStatusDidChange: NSNotification.Name


@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable: NSNotification.Name

@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable: NSNotification.Name


// userInfo contains NSURL with launch URL
// userInfo contains NSString with launch app bundle ID
// userInfo contains NSDictionary with payload
// userInfo contains a UILocalNotification
// userInfo contains object with annotation property list
// app was launched in response to a CoreLocation event.
// userInfo contains an NSArray of NKAssetDownload identifiers
// userInfo contains an NSArray of CBCentralManager restore identifiers
// userInfo contains an NSArray of CBPeripheralManager restore identifiers
// userInfo contains the UIApplicationShortcutItem used to launch the app.

// Key in options dict passed to application:[will | did]FinishLaunchingWithOptions and info for UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
// Sub-Dictionary present in launch options when user activity is present
// Key in user activity dictionary for the activity type
// The presence of this key indicates that the app was launched in order to handle a CloudKit sharing invitation. The value of this key is a CKShareMetadata object.

// userInfo contains NSURL with launch URL
// userInfo contains NSString with launch app bundle ID
// userInfo contains NSDictionary with payload
// userInfo contains a UILocalNotification
// userInfo contains object with annotation property list
// app was launched in response to a CoreLocation event.
// userInfo contains an NSArray of NKAssetDownload identifiers
// userInfo contains an NSArray of CBCentralManager restore identifiers
// userInfo contains an NSArray of CBPeripheralManager restore identifiers
// userInfo contains the UIApplicationShortcutItem used to launch the app.
// Key in options dict passed to application:[will | did]FinishLaunchingWithOptions and info for UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
// Sub-Dictionary present in launch options when user activity is present
// Key in user activity dictionary for the activity type
// The presence of this key indicates that the app was launched in order to handle a CloudKit sharing invitation. The value of this key is a CKShareMetadata object.

// Keys for application:openURL:options:

// value is an NSString containing the bundle ID of the originating application
// value is a property-list typed object corresponding to what the originating application passed in UIDocumentInteractionController's annotation property
// value is a bool NSNumber, set to YES if the file needs to be copied before use

// value is an NSString containing the bundle ID of the originating application
// value is a property-list typed object corresponding to what the originating application passed in UIDocumentInteractionController's annotation property
// value is a bool NSNumber, set to YES if the file needs to be copied before use

// This notification is posted after the user takes a screenshot (for example by pressing both the home and lock screen buttons)
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot: NSNotification.Name
```